# Question about electricity

Tags: electrostatics, energy-conservation, charge

Imagine a wire . Now on both ends of the wire there are 3 electrons. So there is no flow. But if we insert 2 more electrons to one end then there will be a electric potential difference. Now my question is what happens to the energy the we spent on inserting those 2 electrons. Of course the flow is due to the elctrons repeling each other so what happened to the energy spent on creating a potential difference

Answer (score 0):

The energy you're talking about is the work done in creating the p.d i.e.,
$$dW=-qdV$$

So, only external work being done will convert it to electromotive force / electrical energy. With no work done, there won't be any p.d and hence no current flow.

So, in simple words, it is converted to electrical energy.